# "Static validation completed with errors" when submitting xap package

Tags: windows-phone-7

"Static validation completed with errors" with an "Unknown error 5000" when I tried to submit xap package. I believe problems are related to Natural Language selection in Assembly Information because if I set it to say English, Danish or German error is gone. If I try with Serbian or Croatian I'm getting the error I mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application must target at least one of Windows Phone's currently-supported display languages (section 4.4 [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh184844%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)). If your app does not target any additional languages past the neutral resource language, then it will be shown as only supporting the neutral resource language. Serbian and Croatian aren't currently one of the supported display languages (see the current list [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202918%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)).

In your case, that would mean that your app would appear to to the submission application as only supporting Serbian or Croatian and not any of the supported display languages, which goes against the submission guidelines. I imagine this is what is causing your app to fail the submission process.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks. Not sure how I will pass 5.5.1 of Content Validation though. It states...Test Process Required:
1. Review the product description of the
application and verify that it is localized to the
target language.
2. Launch the application.
3. Verify that the UI text of the application is
localized to the target language.

Comment: @Vladimir Đačić You will have to localize the application into one of the supported display languages in addition to Serbian or Croatian and set that display language as the neutral resource language. Then, add the other languages in following the method in the tutorial here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637520(v=VS.92).aspx

Comment: Right, thanks. Also, here is the link I got from MS support when I asked for help. You might find it usefull too http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/87638.aspx